# When I click on one of my new responses in the StackExchange top bar dropdown, the other disappear and I don't know which site to check

Tags: support, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

I am guessing there is a feature I simply don't know about which can get me around the issue I describe in my question: re-stating - sometimes I post to multiple stack exchange sites, say SO and Programmers.  Then replies come in on both.  I see the red circle with a "2" appear and I excitedly click on the first one but don't register what the second one was.  In this scenario it's possible I miss replies.

Is there an easy solution to the issue of my use case here?

Comment: I just mouse right click to open a reply in another browser tab when there are more than one replies. And of course `inbox` tab in [collider](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackexchange-button/info "what's this?") lists it all to me. And there's an "inflated" inbox you can see at http://stackexchange.com/users/171254/aaron-anodide?tab=inbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click the Stack Exchange dropdown in the top left of the header, click on "Inbox". Even after the red circle telling you the number of new notifications has disappeared, those events are still listed in the inbox. Simply click on your inbox, and look down the list until you find the event you didn't click on yet. :)

Or, when you first open the global inbox when you have multiple replies, you can right-click each notification and open each one in a new tab, so you'll have them all open when the red circle goes away.

[image: Global Inbox]

Comment: thanks!, I knew there was going to be something staring me in the face

Answer (score 2):

You can still re-open your inbox and check the messages, just click on the `inbox` link in the dropdown available from the little down-arrow next to the `Stack Exchange` logo:

[image: How to get to the indox]

Alternatively, your Stack Exchange profile also has a global inbox, as part of your profile at https://stackexchange.com/users/171254/aaron-anodide.